# Apparent contradiction to Atiyah-Krull-Schmidt

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space equipped with an anisotropic bilinear form $B\colon V\otimes V\to k$, e.g. with $k=\mathbb{R}$ we can let $B$ be any inner product on $V$.

Let $L$ be the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{P}(V)$, and let $E$ be the vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for which

$$E_{[x]} = \{ y\in V: B(x,y)=0\}.$$
Let $T$ be the trivial bundle $T=V\times \mathbb{P}(V)$.

Given local sections $u\in \Gamma_L(U)$ and $v\in \Gamma_E(U)$ we obtain $u+v\in \Gamma_T(U)$. Conversely, given $w\in \Gamma_T(U)$ we obtain $u\in \Gamma_L(U)$ and $v\in \Gamma_E(U)$ by $B$-orthogonal projection. Since $B$ is bilinear the map $w\mapsto(u,v)$ is algebraic, and since $B$ is anisotropic we have $w=u+v$. Thus it seems we have an algebraic isomorphism

$$T\cong L\oplus E.$$
But $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is complete, so by Theorem 3 of Atiyah's *On the Krull-Schmidt theorem with application to sheaves*, vector bundles over $\mathbb{P}(V)$ should have unique decomposition into indecomposables. Clearly $T$ is a direct sum of $\dim(V)$ copies of the trivial line bundle, so this seems to lead to the false conclusion that $L$ is trivial.

Where am I making a mistake? Vector spaces over algebraically closed fields don't admit anisotropic bilinear forms, so a potential resolution would be if Atiyah's result only applies to varieties over algebraically closed fields, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Are you thinking that $L$ (and I suppose $E$) is trivial because $T$ is?  If you take any embedded manifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then the tangent bundle and normal bundle sum to the trivial bundle, even if the tangent or normal bundle is non-trivial.

Comment: @J126 From my understanding the Atiyah-Krull-Schmidt theorem tells us that such phenomena should be impossible for *algebraic* vector bundles.

Comment: Ok. I'm out of my league there.

Comment: What do you mean by a variety over a non algebraically closed field $k$? Do you mean a geometrically integral scheme of finite type over $k$? If that is the case, your description of the fibres of the vector bundle $E$ has to include points $x$, whose residue field is larger than $k$, and over which the anisotropic condition will be violated. Note that if eg $k={\bf R}$, then the set of lines through $0$ in $k^{d+1}$ do not form the points of a variety in any classical sense (it is only a topological space). In other words, Atiyah's result can only be formulated over an alg. closed. field.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks, I think ignoring the geometric points is probably the issue.